# Upload a file from Azure Functions to Azure Blob using PUT Block

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

We have a React app and want to upload a large file to Azure blob for further processing.
Looked at [this link](https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) which is promising but it uses Storage API within the app. Took the idea to split the file locally and do an upload to the Azure Functions and use ["PUT Block" method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) on blob to complete the upload.

Now facing issue with uploading the file in the Azure Function. Always getting "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format" error.

Following is the code in Azure Function

```
            try
            {
                var files = req.Form.Files;
                var file = files[0];
                var blockId = req.Form["blockId"].ToString();
                
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri("https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/coolstuff"),new StorageCredentials("mykey"));
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
                    await blob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, ms, null);
                }
                return new OkObjectResult("File uploaded");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex, "Error uploading the file");
            }
```

Comment: You are using a really old version of the SDK. If my memory serves me right, you should get an exception of type `StorageException`. Use that instead of a general `Exception` and you should be able to see more details about the error. Ideally, you should see the header name which is giving you the error.

Comment: Was able to resolve this issue. Somehow the header on the client was getting changed back to application/json which was causing the issue. But now getting a different error. Thanks for the suggestion on changing the Exception object.

Comment: @GauravMantri you had written an excellent post back in 2013 [link here](https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/). Did you ever write a post that use the SDK? Can't find a good article around it.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I haven't written any blog posts using SDK. Please edit your question and include your complete code and the problems you are running into. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header on the client was getting changed back to "application/json" from "multipart/form-data" which was causing the issue. I removed the explicit callout to the "multipart/form-data" for the Content-Type in the header which resolved the issue.